# How to prove range of the following operator is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is an infinite dimensional hilbert space and $X_n$ be its $n$ dimensional subspace. Let $P$ denotes the orthogonal projection on $X_n$ from $X$. Also $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to hilbert space $Y$.

Now How to prove that range of this map $TP:X \to Y$ is  closed.

I know the following results

1. For an orthogonal projection range$(P)$ is closed.
2. the range of $T$ is closed in $Y$ if $T$ is open.

But how to prove this i don't know.

Comment: A finite dimensional subspace is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $TP$ is a finite dimensional submanifold, so it is closed.

Comment: can you please explain how? I have Range $P$ is finite dimensional but then after that?

Comment: A finite dimensional vector subspace of a Banach space is closed

Comment: yes i know this result. But my doubt is which property of $T$ we are using here? Thanks in advance

Comment: To see that remark that every norm on a finite dimension space are equivalent, so if you restrict the norm to the finite dimensional subspace, it is equivalent to the norm sup, so if a sequence converges, its coordinates relatively to a base are Cauchy sequence which converges.

Comment: If $S$ is a finite dimensional subspace, then so is $TS$.